# How to set offset from end of a mp4 file by using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

When I have an MP4 video file that last 2 hours and want to remove 30 second from start and 1 minute from end, I use `ffmpeg` like this.

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 video.mp4 -c copy -t 1:58:30 output.mp4
```

It works fine. But I must calculate the length of the output video.
Is there a option to cut off specific time from end of a video file?

I want to write like this.

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 video.mp4 -c copy --offset-from-last 1:00 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option in ffmpeg.

You have to parse the duration using `ffprobe`, then calculate the required offset using a script. To get the total duration:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error input.mp4 \
-show_format -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1
```

This shows the output in `s.msec`. You can also use the `-sexagesimal` option to make it print `HH:MM:SS.msec`, but that makes calculating your offset a little harder.

Simple bash script for doing so:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=/path/to/your/file.mp4
start="30"
offset="60"
duration="$(ffprobe -loglevel error "$input" -show_format -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1)"
end=$(echo "$duration - $offset" | bc)
echo ffmpeg -ss "$start" -i "$input" -c copy -to "$end"
```

Note that you want `-to` instead of `-t`. The former will cut the stream until the point specified, whereas with `-t`, you will end up with a stream of the specified *length*.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of keyframes can lead to imprecision and it doesn't work with subtitle streams but this otherwise works for me.

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i in.mp4 -itsoffset -90 -i in.mp4 -c copy -map 1:a:0 -map 0 -shortest inter.mp4
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -i inter.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -map -0:0 final.mp4
```

`-ss 30` is the start trim. `-itsoffset -90` is the start+end trim.